# about scar and people of God

Tags: levites-leviyim

Is it true that God did put a spiritual mark on His people?

If true I would like to know if a Levi is able to see this spiritual scar.

Comment: no -- do you have any reason to think that this is true? Where did you hear it?

Comment: Is this a "spiritual" mark and it is something that certain tzaddikim can tell  or do you mean bris milah?

Comment: @sabbahillel means circimsicion.

Comment: Hello Marta, welcome to the site! Consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site. This question could be improved if you add why you think it might be true. That gives peoplea place to startlookingfor an answer. Even if it is something you heard, [editing](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/68431/edit) that in would be helpfull.

Comment: Marta, you should register your account if you want to edit this post and be sure we recognize the edit as coming from you

Answer (score 6):

I'm aware of nothing at all like that.

(Some Christian theology discusses "the mark of the beast", but Judaism does not acknowledge that.)

There are plenty of instances of not knowing whether someone is Jewish. In fact, the Talmud tells the story of a certain non-Jew who would travel to Jerusalem, pose as Jewish, and partake in the Passover sacrifice. He was eventually discovered because of something he said that showed complete ignorance of Judaism; not because of any visible signs.

Perhaps you're thinking of *tzara'at*? The Bible ([Leviticus Ch. 13](http://www.bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=3&CHAPTER=13#C2304)) says if a person has certain miraculously-strange skin discolorations (and scars are discussed there), they show it to a priest (a *kohen*, which is a sub-category of a Levite), who can declare the person "ritually impure" and therefore in quarantine for a while. Those laws haven't been applicable for a very long time, though.

And yes, Jewish males are commanded to be circumcised (which does not leave a scar!); but you can have a Jew who is not circumcised (let's say he has hemophilia and it would be severely dangerous to get circumcised), and plenty of non-Jews who are. So that doesn't really prove anything either.

The Talmud says that on the Jewish new year, God judges each person individually "like each member of the herd walking before the farmer", but again nothing about marking.

Comment: and women -- Jewish but not circumcised.